# Why is hive metadata_db formed in current directory and not in spark.sql.warehouse.dir?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql

[Authority](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-hive-tables.html) says:

> When not configured by the hive-site.xml, the context automatically creates metastore_db in the current directory and creates a directory configured by spark.sql.warehouse.dir, which defaults to the directory spark-warehouse in the current directory that the Spark application is started. Note that the hive.metastore.warehouse.dir property in hive-site.xml is deprecated since Spark 2.0.0. Instead, use spark.sql.warehouse.dir to specify the default location of database in warehouse. You may need to grant write privilege to the user who starts the Spark application.

I have checked it as well. One directory gets created in `spark.sql.warehouse.dir` that houses all the data and there is a metadata_db directory in the current directory that stores the metadata for the data in `spark.sql.warehouse.dir`

Also, metadata is needed to retain partition information while reading from hive store. How does one manage this in production then? Should the metadata not be stored at `spark.sql.warehouse.dir` only so that the user does not have to worry about its maintenance?

Comment: The default embedded deployment mode is not recommended for production use due to limitation of only one active SparkSession at a time. https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/content/spark-sql-hive-metastore.html